# Receive Android Intent from adb when app is in the foreground

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, adb

I have my app running in the foreground and when I issue the adb command below I get the Warning message.  It is saying the Intent has been delivered but I'm not sure how to receive it in my MainActivity.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
adb shell am start -a com.ilw.admin.INSTALL_COMPLETE

Starting: Intent { act=com.ilw.admin.INSTALL_COMPLETE }
Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance.
```

AndroidManifest.xml Activity

```
       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="com.ilw_admin.INSTALL_COMPLETE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: What kind of input are you looking for? It's unclear what you've already tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I'm just looking to receive the Intent Action in my MainActivity.  Like you would in ```onCreate()``` if that adb command was run and your app was not running on the Android phone.

Comment: Activity is singleTop, did you check onNewIntent(Intent intent) ?

Comment: @Muneesh that worked perfectly.  Thank you very much.  If you post it as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity is SingleTop as mentioned in the manifest.
So if the activity is already on top of the stack, and the activity is launched again, onNewIntent will be called and intent will be delivered here.

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
   
}
```